# Erro libxml Windows

Tags: windows, lib

Quando fazemos um #include na linguagem c++ usando os caracteres especiais <> onde se encontra a pasta/arquivo desse include?

Estou compilando um programa que baixei e nesse programa ha as seguintes linhas de codigo:

```
28 #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
29 #include <libxml/parser.h>
30 #include <libxml/threads.h>
```

E quando eu tento compilar da o seguinte erro:

```
28  30  C:\Users\joao\Desktop\OT\Projeto OT Global\SOURCE 1.0.6\otpch.h [Error] libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
```

Pois então eu baixei essa biblioteca e gostaria de saber onde ela fica no windows pra eu poder coloca-la no lugar e corrigir esse erro.

Comment: Qual IDE/compilador está a usar?

Comment: Estou usando o Dev-C++

Comment: Já verificou em *c:\dev-c++\include* e c:\dev-c++\Lib\?

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo o [Dev-C++ FAQ](http://www.bloodshed.net/faq.html#5), o diretório do `include` pode ser localizado em:

> C:\Dev-C++\include\

No [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) o diretório (numa instalação normal) geralmente é:

> C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\

No [MingGW](http://www.mingw.org/):

> C:\MinGW\include\

No Unix a pasta [`include`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) pode ser localizado em algum dos seguintes diretórios:

```
/usr/local/include
libdir/gcc/target/version/include
/usr/target/include
/usr/include
```